Can Unity make it so that TMP_Drop is generated entirely based on the template without recalculating the size?
The dropdown generated will have its size recalculated, but the resized dimensions are not what I desire. Moreover, I have not found a way to prevent this recalculation process.
this is recalculate code.
            // Reposition all items now that all of them have been added
            Vector2 sizeDelta = contentRectTransform.sizeDelta;
            sizeDelta.y = itemSize.y * m_Items.Count + offsetMin.y - offsetMax.y;
            contentRectTransform.sizeDelta = sizeDelta;

            float extraSpace = dropdownRectTransform.rect.height - contentRectTransform.rect.height;
            if (extraSpace > 0)
                dropdownRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(dropdownRectTransform.sizeDelta.x, dropdownRectTransform.sizeDelta.y - extraSpace);

Can I stop it?
I hope he can replicate the template exactly without recalculating the size.

As TMP is basically an open package with all code available ... you can simply find it in Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui - copy this folder into the Packages folder. This converts it into an embedded editable package .. then you can simply modify the source code according to your needs. I would for instance create a custom copy of TMP_Dropdown and make your modifications there - this way the normal dropdown still works as usual for other use cases
